# How to prevent other app open my app inside their app when sharing image in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

MyApp use intent-filter to receive image from other App, but when I share image from Telegram, Telegram open new instance of MyApp inside telegram app instead of reopen current instance of MyApp. So 2 instance of MyApp open at the same time. It's different when I share image from WhatsApp to MyApp. Quora App can prevent that. So how to prevent telegram to do that like Quora App? I used single activity with jetpack navigation. Thanks.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe it helps to put this in your manifest in the activity

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working for my case.